# Does a map get slower the longer it is

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, unordered-map

Will a map get slower the longer it is? I'm not talking about iterating through it, but rather operations like `.find()` `.insert()` and `.at()`.

For instance if we have `map<int, Object> mapA` which contains 100'000'000 elements and `map<int, Object> mapB` which only contains 100 elements.

Will there be any difference performance wise executing `mapA.find(x)` and `mapB.find(x)`?

Comment: @CrazyEddie yes it will, but its' not "of course", because unordered_map use hash functions to get an almost constant time

Comment: A 100mil element hash is also going to be slower than one that has 100 elements.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: If each node occupies a separate cache line and the load factor is low, then that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but: The what this whole "O(n)", or Big-O Notation stuff is about. n is the count of the elements here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complexity of lookup and insertion operations on `std::map` is *logarithmic* in the number of elements in the map. So it gets slower as the map gets larger, but only it gets slower only *very* slowly (slower than any polynomial in the element number). To implement a container with such properties, operations usually take a form of *binary search*.

To imagine how much slower it is, you essentially require one further operation every time you double the number of elements. So if you need *k* operations on a map with 4000 elements, you need *k* + 1 operations on a map with 8000 elements, *k* + 2 for 16000 elements, and so forth.

---

By contrast, `std::unordered_map` does not offer you an ordering of the elements, and in return it gives you a complexity that's *constant on average*. This container is usually implemented as a hash table. "On average" means that looking up one particular element may take long, but the time it takes to look up many randomly chosen elements, divided by the number of looked-up elements, does not depend on the container size. The unordered map offers you fewer features, and as a result can potentially give you better performance.

However, be careful when choosing which map to use (provided ordering doesn't matter), since asymptotic cost doesn't tell you anything about real wall-clock cost. The cost of hashing involved in the unordered map operations may contribute a significant constant factor that only makes the unordered map faster than the ordered map at large sizes. Moreover, the lack of predictability of the unordered map (along with potential complexity attacks using chosen keys) may make the ordered map preferable in situations where you need control on the worst case rather than the average.

Comment: Approximately, how many times slower would a 100 million map be than a 100 map? Your edit answered it. Nice to hear it will get exponentially slower and not linearly.

Comment: 100 is roughly 2^7 and 100 million is roughly 2^27, so about 4 times slower. (Think about a road that repeatedly forks left and right. To get to one of 100 destinations would take 7 forks. To get to one of 100 million destinations would take 27 forks. So 4 times as many, roughly.)

Comment: @KaareZ: For binary search, you *add* the base-2 logarithm of the ration, i.e. ld(1M), i.e. roughly 20 comparisons *in addition* to the operation on 100 elements. But then if you have 100 trillion (100 * 10^12) elements, it's only yet another 20 operations.

Comment: Worth to mention:  use of an unordered_map with a good hash function could make the search time constant

Comment: @Christophe How would one go about making a good hash function?

Comment: @KaareZ It depends upon a lot of details about the values of the keys.

Comment: @Christophe: that's a separate question please.

Comment: @KaareZ As Kerrek suggested:optimal hash functions for unordered_map are worth a different question. If you raise it, don't forget to tell something about the distribution of the ints used as key.

Comment: If anything, the cache misses for a large map will hurt much more than logarithmic factor.

Comment: The guarantees in the standard are usually *operation* based.  Time can easily be different: small structures can fit in the cache, large structures may not, generating large (100-fold-plus) slowdowns that are not accounted for in the C++ standard, simply due to size.  As both map and unordered are node based (of necessity by how the standard is phrased, I believe), this can happen in practice at modest container sizes.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard only requires that `std::map` has logarithmic lookup time; not that it is a logarithm of any particular base or with any particular constant overhead.

As such, asking "how many times slower would a 100 million map be than a 100 map" is nonsensical; it could well be that the overhead easily dominates both, so that the operations are about the same speed. It could even well be that for small sizes the time growth is exponential! By design, none of these things are deducible purely from the specification.

Further, you're asking about *time*, rather than *operations*. This depends heavily on access patterns. [To use some diagrams from Paul Khong's (amazing) blog on Binary searches](http://www.pvk.ca/Blog/2012/07/30/binary-search-is-a-pathological-case-for-caches/), the runtimes for repeated searches (look at `stl`, the turquoise line) are almost perfectly logarithmic,

[image: Repeated searches]

but once you start doing random access the performance becomes decidedly non-logarithmic due to memory access outside of level-1 cache:

[image: Random searches]

Note that `goog` refers to Google's `dense_hash_map`, which is akin to `unordered_map`. In this case, even it does not escape performance degradation at larger sizes.

The latter graph is likely the more telling for most situations, and suggests that the speed cost from looking up a random index in a size-100 `map` will cost about 10x less than a size-500'000 map. `dense_hash_map` will degrade *worse* than that, in that it will go from almost-free to certainly-not-free, albeit always remaining *much* faster than the STL's `map`.

In general, when asking these questions, an approach from theory can only give you very rough answers. A quick look at actual benchmarks and considerations of constant factors is likely to fine-tune these rough answers significantly.

Now, also remember that you're talking about `map<int, Object>`, which is very different from `set<uint32_t>`; if the `Object` is large this will emphasize the cost of cache misses and de-emphasize the cost of traversal.

---

#### A pedantic aside.

A quick note about hash maps: Their time complexity is often described as constant time, but this isn't strictly true. Most hash maps rather give you *constant time with very high likelihood* with regards to lookups, and *amortized constant time with very high likelihood* with regards to inserts.

The former means that for most hash tables there is an input that makes them perform less than optimal, and for user-input this could be dangerous. For this reason, Rust uses a cryptographic hash by defaul, Java's [`HashMap`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180) resolves collision with a binary search and CPython [randomizes hashes](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703). Generally if you're exposing your hash table to untrusted input, you should make sure you're using some mitigation of this kind.

Some, like Cuckoo hashes, do better than probabilistic (on constrained data types, given a [special kind of hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing)) for the case where you're worried about attackers, and [incremental resizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Incremental_resizing) removes the amortized time cost (assuming cheap allocations), but neither are commonly used since these are rarely problems that need solving, and the solutions are not free.

That said, if you're struggling to think of why we'd go through the hassle of using unordered maps, look back up at the graphs. They're fast, and you should use them.